# Hawk authentication error with @hapi/hawk

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm trying a basic sample to authenticate a request using **Hawk** scheme and **Hapi** but the hawk plugin fails because it is trying to access a `payload` property that does not exist:

Error:

```
Server started listening on http://localhost:3000
Debug: internal, implementation, error
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined
    at Object.authenticate (D:\TEST\node\sample3\node_modules\@hapi\hawk\lib\plugin.js:45:45)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

The relevant Hawk plugin [code](https://github.com/hapijs/hawk/blob/master/lib/plugin.js) where the error is generated:

```
...
    if (request.route.settings.auth.payload) {
        request.events.once('peek', (chunk) => {
...
```

Server code:

```
    const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');
    const Hawk = require('@hapi/hawk');

    const credentials = {
        John: {
            key: 'secret',
            algorithm: 'sha256'
        }
    };

    const getCredentialsFunc = function (id) {
        return credentials[id];
    };

    const start = async () => {
        const server = Hapi.server({ port: 3000, host: 'localhost' });

        await server.register(Hawk);

        server.auth.strategy('default', 'hawk', { getCredentialsFunc });
        server.auth.default('default');

        server.route({
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/',
            handler: function (request, h) {
                return 'Welcome';
            }
        });

        await server.start();

        console.log('Server started listening on %s', server.info.uri);
    };

    start();
```

Client code:

```
    const Request = require('request');
    const Hawk = require('@hapi/hawk');

    const credentials = {
        id: 'John',
        key: 'secret',
        algorithm: 'sha256'
    };

    const requestOptions = {
        uri: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {}
    };

    const { header } = Hawk.client.header(requestOptions.uri, requestOptions.method, { credentials: credentials, ext: 'some-app-data' });
    requestOptions.headers.Authorization = header;

    Request(requestOptions, function (error, response, body) {
        const isValid = Hawk.client.authenticate(response, credentials, header.artifacts, { payload: body });

        console.log(`${response.statusCode}: ${body}` + (isValid ? ' (valid)' : ' (invalid)'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a PR for this exact problem :)
https://github.com/hapijs/hawk/pull/259